# Search table based on Columns javascript

Tags: javascript, html

> Im having a trouble how can I filter column table using dropdown and search button in javascript. Firstly in dropdown/select I need to choose  what column should I filter and then there is a search input value then you need to click the button search to trigger the filter.
> Is there any expert can help me this?
> reference - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47230147/14704233)
>
> ```html
> <label for="col">Column :</label>
> <select id="col">
>     <option >Customers</option>
>     <option>Location</option>
> </select>
>
> <!-- <input type="number" id="col" placeholder="column" onkeyup="search()" min="0" step="1" /> -->
> <br>
> <label for="val">Filter :</label>
> <input type="text" id="val" placeholder="cell" onkeyup="search()" />
>
> <button >Search</button>
>
> <table id="tab">
>   <tr>
>     <th>Customers</th>
>     <th>Main Location</th>
>   </tr>
>   <tr>
>     <td>josh</td>
>     <td>hawkins</td>
>   </tr>
>   <tr>
>     <td>hanna</td>
>     <td>big sandy</td>
>   </tr>
>   <tr>
>     <td>bonne</td>
>     <td>big sandy</td>
>   </tr>
>   <tr>
>     <td>thomas</td>
>     <td>big sandy</td>
>   </tr>
> </table>
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the search to work correctly, it was necessary to get the current index of the selected item from the drop-down box.

You have declared `col = document.getElementById('col')`, where `col` is the `select` tag. And to get the current index, you need to write this - `col.selectedIndex`, and it should look like this:

```
...
if (regex.test(table.rows[i].cells[col.selectedIndex].innerHTML))
...
```

```js
var table = document.getElementById('tab'),
  col = document.getElementById('col'),
  val = document.getElementById('val');
  col.max = table.rows[0].cells.length - 1;

function search() {
  var regex = new RegExp(val.value || '', 'i');
  for (var i = table.rows.length; i-- > 1;) {
    if (regex.test(table.rows[i].cells[col.selectedIndex].innerHTML)) {
      table.rows[i].style.display = 'table-row';
    } else
      table.rows[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```html
<label for="col">Column :</label>
<select id="col">
    <option >Customers</option>
    <option>Location</option>
</select>

<!-- <input type="number" id="col" placeholder="column" onkeyup="search()" min="0" step="1" /> -->
<br>
<label for="val">Filter :</label>
<input type="text" id="val" placeholder="cell" onkeyup="search()" />

<button >Search</button>

<table id="tab">
  <tr>
    <th>Customers</th>
    <th>Main Location</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>josh</td>
    <td>hawkins</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>hanna</td>
    <td>big sandy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>bonne</td>
    <td>big sandy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>thomas</td>
    <td>big sandy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

second solution:

I added a checkbox to html to adjust the search type by writing a function to `enable/disable` column search for this tag:

html

```
<input id="chbx" type="checkbox">
<label for="chbx">All columns</label>
```

js

```
chbx = document.getElementById('chbx');
var state = 1;

chbx.onclick = function() {
  if (this.checked === true) {
     col.disabled = true;
     state = 0;
     search();
  } else {
     col.disabled = false;
     state = 1;
     search();
  }
}
```

Also, I've set up the counter check in the main search function `search()`. Also, the beauty of this example is that the search is triggered when a set of characters is typed in the input field when trying to `disable/enable` column search.

```js
var table = document.getElementById('tab'),
  col = document.getElementById('col'),
  val = document.getElementById('val'),
  chbx = document.getElementById('chbx');
  col.max = table.rows[0].cells.length - 1;
  var state = 1;
  
  
chbx.onclick = function() {
  if (this.checked === true) {
     col.disabled = true;
     state = 0;
     search();
  } else {
     col.disabled = false;
     state = 1;
     search();
  }
}

function search() {  
  var regex = new RegExp(val.value || '', 'i');
  for (var i = table.rows.length; i-- > 1;) {
   if (state == 1) { 
    if (regex.test(table.rows[i].cells[col.selectedIndex].innerHTML)) {
      table.rows[i].style.display = 'table-row';
    } else {table.rows[i].style.display = 'none'};  
    } 
    if (state == 0) {
     if (regex.test(table.rows[i].innerHTML)) {
      table.rows[i].style.display = 'table-row';
    } else {table.rows[i].style.display = 'none'};
    } 
 }  
}
```

```html
<label for="col">Column :</label>
<select id="col">
    <option >Customers</option>
    <option>Location</option>
</select>
<input id="chbx" type="checkbox">
<label for="chbx">All columns</label>

<!-- <input type="number" id="col" placeholder="column" onkeyup="search()" min="0" step="1" /> -->
<br>
<label for="val">Filter :</label>
<input type="text" id="val" placeholder="cell" onkeyup="search()" />

<button >Search</button>

<table id="tab">
  <tr>
    <th>Customers</th>
    <th>Main Location</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>josh</td>
    <td>hawkins</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>hanna</td>
    <td>big sandy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>bonne</td>
    <td>big sandy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>thomas</td>
    <td>big sandy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This is the third solution. The drop-down list now contains a value for searching across all categories.

```js
var table = document.getElementById('tab'),
  col = document.getElementById('col'),
  val = document.getElementById('val'),
  state = 0;
  col.max = table.rows[0].cells.length - 1;

col.onchange = function() {
  if (col.selectedIndex !== 0) {
    state = 1;
  } else {
    state = 0;
  }
  search();
}

function search() {  
  var regex = new RegExp(val.value || '', 'i');
  for (var i = table.rows.length; i-- > 1;) {
   if (state == 1) { 
    if (regex.test(table.rows[i].cells[col.selectedIndex-1].innerHTML)) {
      table.rows[i].style.display = 'table-row';
    } else {table.rows[i].style.display = 'none'};  
    } 
    if (state == 0) {
     if (regex.test(table.rows[i].innerHTML)) {
      table.rows[i].style.display = 'table-row';
    } else {table.rows[i].style.display = 'none'};
    } 
 }  
}
```

```html
<label for="col">Column :</label>
<select id="col">
    <option>All columns</option>
    <option >Customers</option>
    <option>Location</option>
</select>

<!-- <input type="number" id="col" placeholder="column" onkeyup="search()" min="0" step="1" /> -->
<br>
<label for="val">Filter :</label>
<input type="text" id="val" placeholder="cell" onkeyup="search()" />

<button >Search</button>

<table id="tab">
  <tr>
    <th>Customers</th>
    <th>Main Location</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>josh</td>
    <td>hawkins</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>hanna</td>
    <td>big sandy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>bonne</td>
    <td>big sandy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>thomas</td>
    <td>big sandy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks it works but what if I want to add All in dropdown that should filter all the data table?

Comment: You didn't talk about this in your question.

Comment: Do you want to add a third parameter - Everyone? And filter by two parameters at the same time?

Comment: ,thanks for your response  sorry I forgot to add this  I want to add and search another column in dropdown which is "all" and filter all the data in table, it is possible?

Comment: Yes, I can write search logic across all columns at once. I'll do it now.

Comment: thanks for your response and effort , but iit is possible to put and filter all through  dropdown instead of checkbox?

Comment: Yes. No problem. But only a little later.

Comment: I gave you the third solution - the third snippet. Check pls.

Comment: Thank you this is what I'm looking for

Comment: If you have any questions, I am ready to help more.